# Meta-Pythagorean Triple

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

How can I find all Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ such that the hypotenuse $c$ is a leg in another Pythagorean triple?

For example, $(3,4,5)$ is such a Pythagorean triple because the length of the hypotenuse for this right triangle is 5 and this length shows up as a leg in another Pythagorean triple $(5,12,13)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot easier than it looks like. It turns out that the answer is "all of them". Actually, every single number $n$ greater than $2$ appears as the leg of some pythagorean triangle. If $n$ is not a power of two, the following way works: First, assume $n$ is odd. Then 
$$\left( n,\frac{n^2 - 1}{2}, \frac{n^2 + 1}{2}\right)\quad \text{or} \quad \left(\frac{n^2 - 1}{2}, n, \frac{n^2 + 1}{2}\right)
$$
is a Pythagorean triple. If $n$ is even, say $n = 2^km$ with $m\geq 3$ odd, then use the above on $m$, and scale the pythagorean triple you get by $2^k$.

If $n > 2$ is a power of $2$, use $(3, 4, 5)$ with appropriate scaling.

Comment: @Jack Lam Your question is old but I think I have an answer that will help with your search for a triple with a side matching a given hypotenuse. My functions get downvoted because they are not the standard formula for generating Pythagorean triples but they are the result of a decade of original research and they have the advantage of letting one find matching sides easily.

Comment: Moreover, if $n>2$ and $n\ne 2\mod 4$, $n$ is a leg of a *primitive* Pythagorean triangle. If $n$ is odd, the above answer provides one. If $4\mid n$, let $m$ be $n$'s largest odd factor, as above; then let $t=m$ and $u=n/2m$. Then $(2tu=n, |t^2-u^2|, t^2+u^2)$ is a primitive Pythagorean triangle.

Answer (score 1):

There is a primitive Pythagorean triple with side $A$ equal to any odd number $\ge3$.  We can find those primitives (or the double or perfect square multiples of them) by solving the $A$ or $B$ functions for $n$ and doing a finite search of $m$ values (based on $C$ values in this problem). 
For $A=m^2-n^2$, we let $$n=\sqrt{m^2-A}\implies n=\sqrt{m^2-C}$$ and the search will be limited to values of $m$ where

$$\lceil\sqrt{C+1}\space\rceil\le m\le \biggl\lceil\frac{C}{2}\biggr\rceil$$
For any $m$ that yields positive integer $n$, we have $(m,n)$ for a Pythagorean triple.

For example, we want to find matches for the hypotenuse of $27,36,45$.
$$\text{Our limits are }\lceil\sqrt{45+1}\space\rceil=7\le m\le \biggl\lceil\frac{45}{2}\biggr\rceil=23$$

For most values of $m$, we find $n\notin\mathbb{N}$ but we do find three matches.
$$f(7,2)=(45,28,53)$$
$$f(9,6)=(45,108,117)$$
$$f(23,22)=(45,1012,1013)$$

For $765$ and $1305$, there are $6$ matches each and it appears that the chances of having matches increases with the magnitude of $C$.

Now let's take the triple $(14,48,50)$ where $C$ is even.

$$\text{For }B=2mn\quad n=\frac{B}{2m}\text{ where } \lceil\sqrt{B}\space\space\rceil\le m \le \frac{B}{2}$$

$$\text{for }B=C=50\quad \quad \lceil\sqrt{50}\space\space\rceil=8\le m \le \frac{50}{2}=25$$

$$\text{We find only }n=\frac{50}{2*25}=1\quad \quad f(25,1)=(624,50,626)$$

Answer (score 0):

All pythagorean triples on the integers have the following form:

$a=2xy$

$b=x^2-y^2$

$c=x^2+y^2$

Note every even number can be an $a$.

Any integer can be a $c$ unless the highest power of some prime, p,  in its prime factorization is congruent to 3(mod 4) and is raised to an odd power.

A any $b$ will work. For odd b let $x=(b+1)/2)$ and $y=(b-1)/2$. For even $b$, let $b=2k$. The let $x=k+1$ and $y=k-1$.

Using these rules you can find numbers that belong to both groups.

Comment: The following formula generates the subset of Pythagorean triples where $GCD(A,B.C)$ is an odd square. This includes, no trivials, all primitives and only about $1/3$ the  non-primitives like $(27,36,45)$ that Euclid’s formula produces. Note: conventionally, A is always odd for primitives.
\begin{align*}
  A=(2n-1)^2+                     & 2(2n-1)k      \\ 
  B=  \qquad\quad\quad   & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2\\ 
  C=(2n-1)^2+                    & 2(2n-1)k+ 2k^2\\
\end{align*}

It is the same as though
$
A=(2n-1+k)^2-k^2\quad 
B=2(2n-1+k)k\quad 
C=(2n-1+k)^2+k^2$